Facing problem updating multiple existing items of data in the database from backend in ASP.NET Core
I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core application where I need to update a list of holidays in the database, including dynamic holidays based on user input. However, I'm encountering some issues with my code.
Here's a breakdown of what I'm trying to achieve and the problem I'm facing:
Goal: update existing holidays and add new ones based on user input.
Approach: retrieve selected department IDs and the selected year from the user's input.
Query the database to fetch existing holidays for the selected year.
Iterate through each holiday and update its properties based on the user's input.
Save the changes to the database.
Issue: while my code seems to work for updating single holidays, I'm having trouble extending it to handle updating multiple holidays at once. Specifically, I'm unsure how to properly iterate through the list of holidays and update each one individually in the database.

Please share a sample of the not working and explain what error you get and what you already try to solve the issue.

I'm having some trouble seeing the issues, given that I'm not able to see the code. Please read this and update your question accordingly.

ASP.NET Core is the web stack technology - that doesn't really help us understand what your database is/does/what you use to access it. Show us the table structure / entity class involved, explain what technology stack you use to access the database - and show us the code trying to update

Do you use EF for example? Are you using direct SQL? I would suggest EF if you're not already using it. Then you can do dbcontext.YourEntity.UpdateRange(yourEntitiesToUpdate) -> dbcontext.SaveChanges()

Welcome. You're going to need to give us more details about how you're accessing your data before we can help you. The best option - because you'll learn from doing it, if nothing else - is to write a very minimal update method and post it here. After testing it of course to ensure that it gives the same error.

Your requirement is not clearly, I don't know what you mean about the update multiple rows. Since each row is different I don't know how you want to update multiple rows. Update the row need the key , each row's key is different, so if you want to update multiple rows, you could write a command method and call this method inside your action method row by row.
